# How do we change a lookup relationship to Masterdetail

Tags: administration, lookup, master-detail

I have a lookup relationship and i am looking at ways to convert this relationship to Master Detail.

I have made sure that there are valid ids on the lookup and none of them are null. And when i try to change field type there is only option of Lookup to select. 
What is the process to change the lookup to master detail[image]

Thanks

Comment: is the master detail relation limit on that object is full already?

Comment: is there a way i can check that easily ?

Comment: You can check on Object definition. You can add max 2 master detail relationships on a object

Comment: Wanted a master detail on contract object for opportunity. i dont have any master detail on contract object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some objects, like User, can't have master-detail relationships associated to them, and many standard objects cannot have a custom master-detail relationship to another object. You'll also be prohibited from making master-detail relationships if you've already reached your maximum. If you're looking for the behavior of master-detail relationships on this object, you'll most likely need to implement the sharing, cascade deletes, and/or roll-up summary fields via triggers, flows, etc.

Comment: Its on contract object. i guess the restriction could also be on this object as well

Comment: @Prady Yes, Contract can't have custom master-detail relationships.